# Scope error ? can not read property 'news_property' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, scope, undefined

I've been looking at stack overflow but can't seem to get a good answer, a lot of them seem to be saying try & catch, but I'm wondering if its a scoping error

```
function updateNews() {
    var news_all = $("#news_all");
    var news = data.news.content;
    for (i = 0; i <= news.length; i++ ) {
        var num = i + 1
        var news = data.news.content;
        var  single = news[i];
        if (single.show_item == true) {
            var news_new = '<div class="news-container">' news.title '</div>';
            news_all.append(news_new);
        }

    }
}
```

scripts.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show_item' of undefined

I'm working with a JSON array , and theres a property called 'show_item'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `data.News.content`? What is `News`? How does `News` differ to `data.News`? Obviously, `data.News.content[i]` is undefined for at least one value of `0 <= i < News.length`

Comment: More problems... 1) why reassign `news` inside the loop? You're setting it to the same value every time which is just redundant. 2) You're missing concatenation operators (`+`) in your `news_new` string. 3) Given `news` appears to be some sort of array object, should you be trying to access `news.title` or is it meant to be `single.title`?

Comment: I'm also fairly certain that the code in your (edited) question cannot possibly produce the error *"Cannot read property 'show_item' of undefined"* unless your `data.news.content` array somehow contains `undefined` entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to take a big old guess at what you're actually trying to do and assuming `data.news.content` is an array, it might look something like

```
$('#news_all').append(
  data.news.content
    .filter(newsItem => typeof newsItem === 'object' && newsItem.show_item)
    .map(newsItem => $('<div class="news-container"></div>').text(newsItem.title))
)
```

With this, I'm filtering out `undefined` entries and entries that have `show_item` set to `false`.

I'm then mapping the filtered set to an array of jQuery `<div>` objects with their text set to the relevant title.

This collection of objects is then appended to the `#news_all` element.

For more information, see

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating up to `News.length` when you should be iterating up to `news.length` (case matters). This is causing one of your `news[i]` evaluations to be `undefined`:

```
function updateNews() {
  var news_all = $("#news_all");
  var news = data.News.content;
  for (var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
    if (news[i].show_item == true) {
        news_all.append('<div class="news-container">' news.title '</div>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `i <= news.length - 1` === `i < news.length`

Comment: You really don't need `var news = data.News.content` inside the loop